# How to display data from a foreach within my modal?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a modal to display the data in my list, but when I click the preview button, I always return the last registered record and not the record that I selected

For example, whenever I click on record 1, I want it to return in modal all the information in record 1 only.

This is my foreach

```
    <?php foreach ($ci_properties as $properties) : ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?= $properties['propertie_id'] ?></th>
        <th><?= $properties['bairro'] ?></th>
        <th><?= $properties['empreendimento'] ?></th>
        <th><?= $properties['apartamento'] ?></th>
        <th><?= $properties['cadastro'] ?></th>
        <th><?= $properties['atualizado'] ?></th>
        <th>
            <div><button title="View" class="view btn btn-sm btn-info pull-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-property"<?php echo $properties['propertie_id']; ?>> Visualizar <i class="material-icons">visibility</i></button></div>
        </th>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

And this is my modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="view-property" <?php echo $properties['propertie_id']; ?> class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="view-property" <?php echo $properties['propertie_id']; ?>>Código do imóvel <th><?= $properties['propertie_id'] ?></th></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="view-property">

      <th><?= $properties['propertie_id'] ?></th>
      <th><?= $properties['bairro'] ?></th>
      <th><?= $properties['empreendimento'] ?></th>"

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Deletar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a imagem modal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
This is my list

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Is your modal inside of `foreach` loop?

Comment: No, it is out..

Answer (score 0):

Your `$properties['propertie_id']` variable is printed outside of modal `id`. Change your button's `data-target` attribute and modal's `id` as follows:

```
<button title="View" class="view btn btn-sm btn-info pull-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-property-<?php echo $properties['propertie_id']; ?>"> Visualizar <i class="material-icons">visibility</i></button>

<div id="view-property-<?php echo $properties['propertie_id']; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

Comment: So, where does `$properties` array in your modal come from? Can you provide more code about your modal?